# How can I create an SVG triangle within another triangle using only one path?

Tags: html, svg, vector

[What is supposed to be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI4sQ.png)

Hi everyone,
I am trying to create something that looks like that using SVG path and I can only use one path. So far what I have is only the big triangle. I know that to make the small one inside i need to add more stop points however I can't seem to figure out the exact ones that are needed. Please help me.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg viewBox="0 0 960 960">

  <path d="M350 0 L275 90 L425 90 Z"  fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke="purple"/>


</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `M` command inside the `<path>` `d` attribute to move the virtual pen around without drawing a line. That way you are able to move the pen to the next position and start a new line using the `L` command from that new position. You can use any combination of these commands to move the virtual pen around and draw lines. The following should give the desired output:

```
<path d="M350 0 L275 90 L425 90 L350 0 M312.5 45 L387.5 45 L350 90 L312.5 45"  
      fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke="purple"/>
```

You may want to have a look at this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html#setting-and-moving-the-pen) for some examples and an explanation of the commands, that are available for drawing a path.